# Windows IDE for Unix application?

Tags: debugging, unix, ide, cross-platform, aix

We have created C&C++ applications based on Aix 6.1 (fortran for some models).

To improve our productivity (we use emacs or vi as editor, xlc/xlC/xlf as compiler, dbx to debug, IBM Synergy as configuration management tool), we are looking for an windows IDE to allow:

```
to modify our source code more easily,
to compile as if we are under unix
```

We also are logging for a graphical debugger.

Thank you for some ideas

Answer (score 0):

I think that Emacs has been ported to Windows. And also GCC and Gnu make.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with remote developing for AIX/Unix on Windows via a couple of routes.

Eclipse has some options.   You can "mount" your project via ssh/rcp, and it will run the compiler remotely capturing the output.   I did't attempt debugging but I assume support is there as well, especially if you use gdb.

[BVRDE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bvrde/) is another option.   Works nicely.    [This link](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/bvrde.htm) is also valid.

I also worked with [XBuildStudio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xbuilddev/), it has some similar features to BVRDE.

Give them a try and see if any of them work for you.

Comment: I am very interessed in testing BVRDE.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a good one, but personally I prefer Codeblocks with Fortran plugin.